# How to remove XML node by attribute

Tags: c#, xml

XML

```
<WorkTable>
    <Days>
      <Day id="0" name="Monday"/>
      <Day id="1" name="Tuesday"/>
      <Day id="2" name="Wednesday"/>
      <Day id="3" name="Thursday" />
      <Day id="4" name="Friday"/>
      <Day id="5" name="Saturday"/>
      <Day id="6" name="Sunday"/>
    </Days>
    <SpecialDays>
      <Day date="22.07.2015"/>
      <Day date="24.07.2015"/>
    </SpecialDays>
</WorkTable>
```

This code doesn't remove the node from xml. Could you help me to find problem?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(localXMLpath + xmlFileName);
XmlNode delNode= doc.SelectSingleNode("/WorkTable/SpecialDays/Day[@date='24.07.2015']");
delNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(delNode);
doc.Save(localXMLpath + xmlFileName);
```

Comment: It should be same as i fixed

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: are you sure your problem isn't that it overwrites the file? the code works OK

Comment: No, it doesnt give an error. When i open xml i see nothing changed.

Comment: If you want to remove the node with date 24.07.2015, it's working fine.

Comment: @rbm , yeah now i see it doesnt overwrite the file. When i give a different file name i see code works fine. So how can i overwrite it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015965/c-sharp-the-close-method-of-xml-loadfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works OK, the problem is that you're trying to overwrite the file you've read the data from.

See this answer [C# : the close method of Xml.Load(file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015965/c-sharp-the-close-method-of-xml-loadfile)

Answer (score 3):

This should works:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xdoc.Element("WorkTable").Element("SpecialDays").Elements("Day")
     .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("date") == "24.07.2015")
     .Remove();
xdoc.Save(filename);
```