# How do I close an XMLDocument in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am importing information from XML files into a SQL Database. The import is working fine but some of the XML files have errors in them so therefore the code fails. I catch the exception and try to move the file to an error folder but as I was previously reading from the file I get an error saying the file is in use by another process. I have searched but havent came across any way of curing this yet. I have tried saving the document but still is in use when I try to move, Below is a sample of the code where I try to move the file for reference. Any suggestions on how to cure this would be great and thanks in advance for the information.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    doc.Load(st);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    doc.Save(st);
    if (File.Exists(st))
        File.Move(st, st + "\\Error");
}
```

Comment: can you specify your folder structure. Where your XML  file currently exists and where you are trying to move it ?

Comment: Are you sure it's XMLDocument holding it open? It should never do that since it just loads it in and that's that.

Comment: `XmlDocument` is unable to load file content, but the file is still in use. Don't try to move the file, just copy it, and perform a cleanup later.

Comment: The folder structure is as follows, main/in is the import folder then once an error occurs I am trying to move it to main/error. The move works fine when the file imports correctly as I move it to a complete folder.

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015965/c-sharp-the-close-method-of-xml-loadfile

I think doc = null and GC.Collect will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    doc.Load(st);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //doc.Save(st);                      -- why do you need to save a file that exists?
    //if (File.Exists(st))               -- it returns always true
    //    File.Move(st, st + "\\Error"); -- wrong path

    File.Move(st, Path.Combine("C:\\Error", Path.GetFileName(st)));
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks, the save, check if exists etc were jsut testing different things to see if it freed up the file. Thanks